How to run command from extension code and restart if this already running?
I need to run command platformio-ide.build with vscode.commands.executeCommand, but if this command already running, VS Code asks The task 'PlatformIO: Build (ardustat)' is already active. [Terminate task] [Restart task]. I need to  automatically restart the command in this case. What do I need to do? I've tried to read VS Code docs, but not found anything.

you could raise an issue ticket asking the maintainers to add a command that builds and restarts first if a build is already happening. if you do raise such an issue ticket, please add a link here to it.
